# What are the five basic internal structures of verb phrases?

Tags: phrases, verbs, syntactic-analysis, verb-patterns

I can't get my head around this.

I found this answer. Can anyone tell me if this makes sense? Also if anyone can reccomend some literature (school books don't cover this question).

Vintr (+ A)            She walks slowly.

Vl +  SC (+A)          Jelena is beautiful.

Vmtr + DO (+A)         I read a book yesterday.

Vdtr+ IO + DO (+A)     Mary wrote her a letter.

Vctr + DO + OC (+A)    I found it very interesting

Comment: Found it in some seminar paper. It only mentions it, and there is nothing in the bibliography.. This is the sentence before the upper text:

the internal structure of the verb phrase depends on type of the verb and it can take various forms, such as:

Comment: Can you post a link to this paper?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw68_SwRUVHdUlJGZlZvb0t5LU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Five basic types of sentences (according to verb types):](http://carrychen.tripod.com/grammar.html) The fifth one there is given as **S + V + IO + DO ( Subject + Dative Verb + Indirect Object +
Direct Object )**

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's number 4 here. I have no idea what the subscripts to V mean (apart from intr=intranstive; dtr = ditransitive, probably). What are *l, mtr* and *ctr*?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: Search me. I'd never heard of "Five basic types of sentences" before I read this question, and that exact string gets just **7** hits in Google. Mind you, "**Four** basic types of sentences" gets over **5000** hits, and I'd never heard of that until I just searched for it halfway thru writing this comment. Off the top of my head I can't see that the 5 types presented by OP here are particularly useful categories, but it's not something I know or care about much.

Answer (score 1):

This preceding section from your source helps decipher it:

> Unlike intransitive verbs, transitive verbs take one or more objects and they can be classified by the number of objects they take. Verbs that require only two arguments, a subject and a single direct object, are mono-transitive. Verbs that take two objects, a direct object and an indirect object, are "di-transitive" or less commonly "bi-transitive". A complex transitive is a verb that requires both a direct object and another object or an object complement. In a complex-transitive construction, the object complement identifies a quality or attribute pertaining to the direct object.

---

I'm not sure why there is no mention of the subject. On the other hand, I think the `(+A)` refers to an optional adjunct phrase (which is missing in several of these examples).

> Vintr (+ A) She walks slowly.

- [Intransitive verb](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=navigating/verbphrase/intransitive)

> Vl + SC (+A) Jelena is beautiful.

- [Linking verb](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=navigating/verbphrase/linking) + subject complement

> Vmtr + DO (+A) I read a book yesterday.

- Mono-[transitive verb](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=navigating/verbphrase/transitive) + direct object

> Vdtr+ IO + DO (+A) Mary wrote her a letter.

- [Di-transitive verb](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=navigating/verbphrase/ditransitive) + indirect object + direct object

> Vctr + DO + OC (+A) I found it very interesting

- [Complex-transitive verb](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=navigating/verbphrase/complextrans) + direct object + object compliment

---

I'm not sure what you think may not make sense, but these terms weren't created by the author of that paper. However, it's important to realize that most verbs fall into more than one of these categories. (In fact, [this source](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/english-verbs-copular-intransitive-transitive-ditransitive-and-ambitransitive/) has complex-transitive as a subtype of ditransitive, and lists "ambitransitive" as the last category.)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an attempt to classify English verbs based on transitivity, argument licensing, and sentence word order. Some (necessarily simplified) terminology may help:

> Transitive verbs convey action to objects; intransitive verbs don't.
>
> An *argument*<sup>*</sup> is a syntactic unit necessary to
>   complete the sense of the verb, the absence of which will make the
>   utterance ungrammatical.
>
> An *adjunct* is a syntactic unit that adds information but the
>   presence of which is unnecessary to make a sensible and grammatical
>   sentence.<sup>**</sup>

There are three types of intransitive verbs. The first don't express action at all, but rather state information, particularly equivalency. These verbs, sometimes called *linking verbs* (Vl) or *copulative verbs*, license a single complement called a *predicate complement* or a ***subjective complement***):

> **[1a]** Jelenna (S) is (Vl) **beautiful** (SC)

This is the second classification in the OP. Notice two things -- firstly, an adjunct is possible but not necessary to make 1a grammatical, i.e., the prepositional phrase below adds information, and its absence does not make 1a ungrammatical.

> **[1b]** Jelenna (S) is (Vl) **beautiful** (SC) in an ethereal way (A)

Secondly, linking verbs license exactly one argument. We can't leave out the complement:

> **[1c]** *Jelenna (S) is (Vl)

and we can't add a second argument:

> **[1d]** *Jelenna (S) is (Vl) **beautiful** (SC) **talented** (SC)

To do this we have to combine the two adjectives into a single complement with a coordinator like *and*:

> **[1e]** Jelenna (S) is (Vl) **beautiful and talented** (SC).

The examples are of complements that are adjectives, but they can be noun phrases as well:

> **[1f]** Jelenna (S) is (Vl) **a dancer** (SC).

Some verbs don't license objects at all. These are sometimes called *atransitive* verbs:

> **[2a]** She (S) walks (Vintr) slowly (A).

We can drop the adjunct: 2b is an acceptable answer to the question "How does she get to work?"

> **[2b]** She (S) walks (Vintr).

Other verbs license at most one object, i.e., the object is optional, and if it's missing the verb is used intransitively. If you ask your neighbor why her child isn't in preschool, she might say by way of explanation:

> **[3a]** He (S) bites (Vintr).

By which you will understand the missing object as

> **[3b** He (S) bites (Vmtr) **other children** (DO).

The atransitive and optional but missing object are two usages grouped in the OP's first classification.  The type of **v**erb that we met in 3b above licenses one object called a ***direct object***; these **v**erbs are called ***m***ono**tr**ansitive:

> **[4a]** I (S) read (Vmtr) **a book** (DO) yesterday (A).

Again, the adjunct is optional, and a missing direct object makes the sentence awkward if not impossible, and sometimes outright impossible. This works:

> **[4b]** I (S) put (Vmtr) **the suitcase** (DO) in the car (A).

This doesn't:

> **[4c]** *I (S) put (Vmtr) in the car (A).

Monotransitive verbs form the OP's third classification. Some verbs license two objects. These **v**erbs are called ***d***i**tr**ansitive, and they come in two flavors, the fourth and fifth classifications in the OP. The first type of ditransitive verb is a verb of giving or transfer and licenses a **direct object** (the thing given) and an ***indirect object*** (the person to whom the thing is given):

> **[5a]** Mary (S) wrote (Vdtr) ***her*** (IO) **a letter** (DO).

The indirect object comes between the verb and the direct object. Thus it is ungrammatical to say

> **[5b]** *Mary (S) wrote (Vdtr) **a letter** (DO) ***her*** (IO?).

Indirect objects must be noun phrases; adjectives won't do:

> **[5c]** *Mary (S) wrote (Vdtr) ***intricate*** (IO?) **a letter** (DO).

The second type of ditransitive verb is a verb of labeling or classification, and it licenses a **direct object** and an ***objective complement***:

> **[6a]** I (S) found (Vdtr) **it** (DO) ***very interesting*** (OC).

Here the complement is an adjective, but it could well be a noun:

> **[6b]** They (S) elected (Vdtr) **him** (DO) ***president*** (OC).

But in either case, the complement must follow the object. The next two sentences are ungrammatical:

> **[6c]** *I (S) found (Vdtr) ***very interesting*** (OC?) **it** (DO).
>   **[6d]** *They (S) elected (Vdtr) ***president*** (OC?) **him** (DO).

These five classifications cover the only licensing patterns that English allows. In particular, there are no **v**erbs that are ***tr***i**tr**anstive, i.e., those that license three objects. There is some dispute whether any language licenses three objects, but some come close, and it's easy to see what a hypothetical tritransitive verb might look. Let's say it's a verb of exchange that requires one direct object for the thing originally held by the subject, an indirect object for the person receiving the first direct object, and a second direct object for the thing originally held by the person named as the indirect object. This would look something like:

> **[7]** *John (S) traded (Vttr?) him (IO) a bicycle (DO<sub>1</sub>) [for a] lawnmower (DO<sub>2</sub>?).

But this is as mythical as the unicorn, so we're left with the classifications of the OP.

---

* Traditionally, subjects are counted as arguments, but the classification here is about verbs, so the discussion is about objects.

** That's what the "(+A)" means in the OP, *+A* for the addition of an adjunct; parentheses to indicate that the adjunct is optional.